# How did the discovery of the platypus affect Linneaus' taxonomy?

Tags: biology, taxonomy

I heard there was a lot of controversy in the royal scientific societies when the first specimens of platypus were shown. How did this affect the taxonomy of animals used at the time, if at all? Has any (other) animal shook the notion of Linneaus' taxonomy, at least temporarily?

Comment: "Effect" and "affect" have different meanings in English. I think you mean the latter.

Comment: Sorry, my English is not native. But I guess the question is still clear.

Comment: @fdb You're right, that should be 'affect'. It is encouraged that you simply edit these type of things if you spot them: Please do so in the future :)

Comment: I do not have it at hand, but it seems that some answer to your first question could be found in Kant and the Platypus : Essays on Language and Cognition by Umberto Eco (1997).